# Can $x'x$ be written as correlation matrix?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, matrix, centering

$x'x=$ $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
         \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{1i}-\bar X_1)^2&\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{1i}-\bar X_1)(X_{2i}-\bar X_1)\cdots & \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{1i}-\bar X_1)(X_{ki}-\bar X_k) \\
       \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{2i}-\bar X_1)(X_{1i}-\bar X_1)&\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{2i}-\bar X_2)^2\cdots \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{2i}-\bar X_2)(X_{ki}-\bar X_k)  \\
        \vdots &\vdots&\vdots \\
        \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{ki}-\bar X_k)(X_{1i}-\bar X_1)&\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{ki}-\bar X_k)(X_{2i}-\bar X_2)\cdots & \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{ki}-\bar X_k)^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

how can i transform it to correlation matrix as :

$$x'x=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & r_{12}\cdots & r_{1k}\\
        r_{21} & 1\cdots & r_{2k} \\
        \vdots &\vdots&\vdots \\
         r_{k1} &  r_{k2}\cdots &1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$?

I know the elements are  the numerator of correlation, i.e., 
$$r_{ij}=\frac{\sum_{u=1}^{n}(X_{iu}-\bar X_i)(X_{ju}-\bar X_j)}{\sqrt{\sum_{u=1}^{n}(X_{iu}-\bar X_i)^2\sum_{u=1}^{n}(X_{ju}-\bar X_j)^2}}$$
.But i can't transform it to correlation formula.

Comment: is this homework? Check the [self-stufy tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p_i = [x'x]_{ii}$ be the $i$th diagonal element of $x'x$. Now define the $k\times k$ diagonal matrix $s$ so that $[s]_{ii} = 1/\sqrt{p_i}$ and all non-diagonal elements equal to zero Then I think the correlation matrix is
$$
r = s x'x s
$$

Comment: How did you find the way so quickly?

Comment: @harry That's a standard result from matrix algebra.